# How to get access to data folder on a real device

Tags: android, database, directory, root

I am creating Database it runs perfectly. I can access database on simulator but can't on real device. Anybody can help me how can i get root rights to access data folder when running app on real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide enough detail about where you are writing your database files. It sounds like you are trying to write to [an area you are not allowed](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html). You shouldn't get root access. The easy thing to do is save in [your app's private area](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). You can also [try external storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html).

Comment: Thanks jbm for reply. Very useful suggestion. Can you tell me how to access database through android/tools/command prompt when running on emulator? I can't find command prompt in my android tools directory there is sqlite3.exe.

Comment: jbm MyDatabase is created in data/data/packagename/.